# How much time the Amazon EC2's instance stay in Running state without activity?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I know that the charging of the most products of amazon is calculated by seconds of activity.

But I didn't get when this charge is stopped ( after X time of inactivity ).

Answer (score 1):

You are charged for the entire time an EC2 instance exists and is in the **Running** state. EC2 instances are not charged based on active vs. idle state. As long as the server is running you are being charged for it.

This statement is not really correct:

> I know that the charging of the most products of amazon is calculated
>   by seconds of activity.

For AWS services where you have to provision a server of a specific size, like RDS, Redshift, ElastiCache, etc. you are charged by the hour, for every hour the server is running. This used to be the case for EC2 as well, but it was recently changed to per-second billing. Even after this change EC2 still charges for every second you have provisioned the server resources, and does not care about how many of those seconds you were actively using the server.

The only AWS compute service that charges per seconds of activity is AWS Lambda.

Comment: Thanks! Then basically, this Amazon's calculator https://image.prntscr.com/image/BmmiEAvYSmqOXX0uvF1jqw.png for Amazon EC2, in config of "Usage" will it have always to be setted "100% utilized/month" ?

Comment: Will the server exist, and be running ever hour of the day, every day of the month? For something like a web server the answer to that is probably "yes". But there are plenty of reasons you might want to run a server for only a few hours a day, a few hours a month, etc., in which case you would use one of the other values in the drop-down of the price calculator.